# Cannot match the 2nd option in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex is:

```
\WAmount\W.*?\bspecified in\b(.*)\bof this Annex\b\s
```

I need to match any words or characters between the word in and the word of this Annex.

It seems to work for the first sentence but is not matching the last sentence with the word Other. Any ideas how I can match this?

Input:

```
(A) “Amount” has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(a) of this Annex.

(A) “Amount” has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(b) of this Annex.

(A) “Amount” has the meaning specified in Other of this Annex.
```

I need to extract 3 from the above not always knowing what the words are between in AND of this Annex.

Comment: Regex dialect varies across tools. Please add a tag for the tool you are using.

Comment: Assuming this is Python 3 regex, I don’t see why this would match any of these. It’s looking for a whitespace character after `Annex`, but there’s always a period there.

Comment: Actually, you should show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: even if I take off the \s, it's not matching. It only matches Paragraph 3(a) not Paragraph3(b) or Other               \WAmount\W.*?specified in(.*)of

Comment: Well, post your code and clarify what language you’re using, then. This is too vague to do anything with.

Comment: Language: java script Code: \WAmount\W.*?specified in(.*)of this Annex Expecting capture groups to be: Paragraph 3(a), Paragraph 3(b), Other

Comment: If I remove `\s` it works for me: https://regex101.com/r/BThI2J/2

Comment: Hmm. It seems to only match Paragraph(a) for me, not the others

Answer (score 0):

IF your requirement is to extract any digits between these specified words, then this one should help

```
(.*)in(.*([0-9]+).*)of this Annex
```

Comment: I think he wants to match anything, not just a number. He's complaining that it's not matching the last example.

Comment: he wrote: **I need to match any words or characters**